# Why did the USA fail to be the first rocket power?

Tags: history, spaceflight-firsts

This question is more on the history side. What I want to know is what the differences between the USA and Germany before 1945 were that led to the States falling behind in space technology.

The United States could boast:

- Robert H. Goddard, a pioneer of rocketry
- Theodore von Kármán and his associates at Caltech
- Huge industrial potential

More specifically, I'm interested in pre-war progress (the Manhattan project did divert a bit of resources during the war).

NOTE: I'm not asking for **subjective opinions**. Please back your argument with historical documents, memoirs, reports or other evidence.

Comment: I think this should be migrated to History.

Comment: @gerrit - historians poor rocket scientists make. (C) Yoda.

Comment: The reasons for this may very well be political and not of scientific or technological nature.

Comment: @gerrit: I think this would make an excellent History.SE question.  But it also seems ontopic here.  Plenty of sites have a [tag:history] tag which they use to discuss the history of their topic of interest.  But it's really up to the community at large to decide. This might make a good [Meta] question, if you feel strongly.

Comment: @JonEricson : Done (http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/questions/270/are-space-exploration-history-questions-on-topic-here) :)

Comment: Yoda has a point ;-) But in this special case, I am with @gerrit. From my point of view, there is just no technical answer here. One needs to dig deep in politics, economy and sociological aspects for understanding what happened.

Comment: As a regular on History.SE, I must agree with @gerrit - it's a better fit there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is that Germany focused on rockets as part of their program of improving artillery. The focus being delivering munitions at long ranges. The initial work was done at Kummersdorf and had enough progress to keep on going resulting in the development of the A4 rocket.

In contrast Goddard and von Kármán worked on other types of projects, like assisted takeoff for aircraft, which had no clear path of development to a long range rocket. While Goddard tried to convince the US Army of the value of long range rockets ultimately the work they assigned him would not create any opportunity to develop that technology.

Comment: Yes, that sums the outcome nicely, but the Army **could** choose to concentrate on rockets. It didn't. ("It" is a misleading pronoun - **somebody** dumb did not do the right thing).

Comment: The V-2, while effective as a piece of propaganda, wasn't Germany's best possible use of the resources and manpower it used. It's quite possible that the US Army did the right thing by not wasting efforts on rockets.

Comment: The US, Russia and Germany all used short-range rocket artillery (Calliope,  Katyusha, Nebelwerfer), so it wasn't like Germany was the only power playing with rocket-powered weapons, period. But Germany was the only player to attempt _long-range_ ballistic rockets. But they could still only hit targets in western Europe. If the US were to build similar systems, it'd have to be done in the US, meaning they'd be able to hit... well, other parts of the US. Not much point in that.

Comment: @RussellBorogove is correct. The V-2 cost about as much as a medium bomber, which was reusable with longer range, better accuracy, and bigger bomb payload. The real military use of such rockets came later with atomic weapons and/or orbital carrier rockets to put military satellites into orbit, either one of which would be asking a lot of vision from someone in the early 20th century (when Goddard worked). But note: a solid rocket V-2 would be much cheaper since it would have virtually no moving parts. It would make an interesting question as to why a solid fuel was not invented sooner.

Comment: @DrZ214 : Solid fuel was invented long before the V-2, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket. The liquid fuel V-2 needed a lot of moving parts for stabilization and attitude control. A solid fuel V-2 would have only some moving parts less, those used for pumping the fuel in the liquid fuel V-2, see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregat_4#Steuerung

Answer (score 14):

Mostly because China was the [first rocket power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_rockets), a few hundred years before the USA existed.

Answer (score 4):

Choosing not to invest in long range rocketry during the war was the correct decision. Due to their high cost it wasn't until long range rockets grew powerful enough to carry miniaturized nuclear weapons that they became a militarily useful asset to the US. Bombers were a much more cost effective way to deliver high explosives on a target.  And while >99% of bomber crews couldn't place their bombs any closer than a mile of their target except via sheer luck; the same was true of 100% of long range rockets during that time period.